# Attributes of OPC UA

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I have to create a `ModelDesign.xml` file to modelling information for my OPC UA server. I came across this model:

```
<Object SymbolicName="ANIMAL:Cat" TypeDefinition="ANIMAL:CatType">
    <Description>A Cat named Cattie</Description>
    <References>
        <Reference IsInverse="true">
            <ReferenceType>ua:Organizes</ReferenceType>
            <TargetId>ANIMAL:AnimalSet</TargetId>
        </Reference>
    </References>
    <Children>
        <Property SymbolicName="ANIMAL:Name" DataType="ua:String" AccessLevel="Read">
            <DefaultValue>
                <uax:String>Cattie</uax:String>
            </DefaultValue>
        </Property>
        <Property SymbolicName="ANIMAL:LegCount" DataType="ua:UInt32" AccessLevel="Read">
            <DefaultValue>
                <uax:UInt32>4</uax:UInt32>
            </DefaultValue>
        </Property>
    </Children>
</Object>
```

I also see this:
[OPC UA S7 communication manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcxsZ.png)

I'm wondering where can I find **all the attributes** supported by OPC UA and **their values** cause this file can be designed manually and there is no intellisense to help with this.
Like the `AccessLevel` above, it has 4 values corresponding to different characteristics.
I have looked at [text](https://stackoverflow.com) (this no longer exist), [text](http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd), and [text](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part5/) but I just get lost.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of OPC UA attributes is in the OPC UA specifications, here:

- https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part3/v104/docs/4.3.3
- https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part3/v104/docs/5.9
- https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part5/v104/docs/5

In particular, the attributes, when used in the Information Model XML, are described here:

- https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part6/v104/docs/F

Comment: Still not getting this but thanks for your information.

Comment: What specifically are you not getting?

Comment: Hi, https://reference.opcfoundation.org/Core/Part6/v104/docs/F does provide some example but it still not has all the values it can be. And it is for `nodeset2.xml` which the value can be represented in different way, for example `AccessLevel="3"` (in nodeset2) and `AccessLevel="Read"` (in ModelDesign.xml). I'm new to opc ua, hope I describe it clearly.